# Sync NoSQL with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, nosql, synchronization

Is there a way to sync NoSQL and SQL databases?

My problem is: We have a software that uses MSSQL. We also have a mobile application that uses MongoDB. We want to sync data (on create/update) between those databases. Mostly from MongoDB to MSSQL.

It is not a problem for us (if we have to) to use different NoSQL DBMs, but we can't find clear instructions of how to sync those two the way i described.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to migrate data from MongoDB to SQL-Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986360/is-it-possible-to-migrate-data-from-mongodb-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at CDC (Change Data Capture) tools that allow you to capture events from your source database (in this case MSSQL) and deal with the event to update/create/delete data in the NoSQL database.

I invite you to look at https://debezium.io/ and the MSSQL Connector & MongoDB connector:

- [MS SQL Server Connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/sqlserver.html)
- [MongoDB Connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mongodb.html)